# Map Class extended by List<T> to List<T> using auto mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having issues mapping below source and destination classes.

```
public class Source
{
  public InnerSourceListExtendedClass InnerSourceListExtended {get;set;}
}

public class InnerSourceListExtended : List<InnerSource>
{
}

public class InnerSource{
 public string prop1 {get;set;}
 public string prop1 {get;set;}
}

public class Destination
{
  public List<InnerDestination> InnerDestination {get;set;}
}

public class InnerDestination
{
  public string prop1 {get;set;}
  public string prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

My current mapping configuration is

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
ForMember(dest => dest.InnerDestination , opts => opts.MapFrom(src => 
src.InnerSourceListExtended));
```

Not able to map using above mapping configuration, it is throwing an exception " Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\Source -> Destination."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you should subclass `List<T>`: Have you seen this (classic) QA post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: `List<InnerDestination>` is not compatible with `InnerSourceListExtendedClass` because `InnerSourceListExtendedClass` extends `List<InnerSource>` **not** `List<InbnerDestination>`. It's like trying to map `SubclassOfListOfString` from `List<Int32>`. Do you define a mapping between `InnerSource` and `InnerDestination`?

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I did not initially defined a mapping between InnerSource and InnerDestination. It worked after defining it.